# Как в JFrame взаимодействовать с переменными, созданными в разных методах actionPerformed?

Tags: java, jframe

В методе `actionPerformed` одной `JButton` у меня выполняются определенные операции с переменными, например:

```
double t1 = (int) spinner.getValue();
double t2 = (int) spinner.getValue();
t = t1 + t2;
```

Мне нужно, чтобы в `actionPerformed` другой `JButton` можно было взаимодействовать с переменной `t`, к примеру тупо вывести в консоль. Однако он же её не знает. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

На ум приходит как минимум два варианта:
1. Передавать в оба метода actionPerformed экземпляр одного класса, который будет являться мостом между методами.
К примеру одна кнопка вызывает у него setT, а вторая getT.
2. Создать Singleton и так же с ним взаимодействовать из обоих методов.